# Could we use DCT with pointwise convergence in probability?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm interested in finding the limit in probability of an integral
$$
\int_{0}^\infty f(X_n, t) \, \pi(\mathrm{d} t),
$$

where $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables and $\int_{0}^\infty \pi(\mathrm{d} t) = 1.$

I know the pointwise limit in probability of $f(X_n, t)$ and I can bound the function $|f(x, t)|$ by a function $h(t)$ that is integrable $\pi( \mathrm{d} t)$. Is that enough to bring the probability limit inside the integral?

More precisely, I have
\begin{align*}
f(X_n, t) &\rightarrow_P f(X, t) \\
|f(x, t)| &\le h(t),\, \, \int_{0}^\infty h(t) \, \pi(\mathrm{d} t) < \infty
\end{align*}
Is it true that
$$
\int_{0}^\infty f(X_n, t) \, \pi(\mathrm{d} t) \rightarrow_P \int_{0}^\infty f(X, t) \pi(\mathrm{d} t) ?
$$

My thoughts: It looks like I should be able to apply the dominated convergence theorem (DCT), somehow. I'm confused because it differs from the textbook examples I saw when I took a basic course in analysis. For example, I'm taking a limit in probability outside the integral. I haven't applied DCT like that before: the limit outside the integral was a "regular" limit.

References or answers are both appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I added absolute value to $f$. Is it okay?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$

\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^\infty \left(f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right)\pi(\mathrm dt)\right| &\le \frac\epsilon2 \int_{0}^\infty \mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \le \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi(\mathrm dt) + \int_{0}^\infty \left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right|\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi\left(\mathrm dt\right)\\
&\le \frac\epsilon 2 + 2\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi(\mathrm dt)
\end{align}

With that we have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left[\left|\int_0^\infty \left(f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right)\pi(\mathrm dt)\right| \ge \epsilon\right] &\leq \mathbb P\left[\frac\epsilon 2 + 2\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi(\mathrm dt) \ge \epsilon\right]\\
&= \mathbb P\left[2\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi(\mathrm dt) \ge \frac\epsilon 2\right]\\
&= \mathbb P\left[\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi(\mathrm dt) \ge \frac\epsilon 4\right]\\
&\le \frac{\mathbb E\left[\displaystyle\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\pi(\mathrm dt)\right]}{\frac\epsilon 4}\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}(t)\right]\pi(\mathrm dt)}{\frac\epsilon 4}\\
&= \frac{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty h(t)\mathbb P\left[{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}\right]\pi(\mathrm dt)}{\frac\epsilon 4}\\
&= \frac4\epsilon \int_0^\infty g_n(t)\pi(\mathrm dt)
\end{align}

where $g_n(t) = h(t)\mathbb P\left[{\left|f\left(X_n, t\right) - f(X,t)\right| \ge \frac\epsilon 2}\right]$. By the assumption, you have $g_n(t)$ converges to $0$ pointwise and since $g_n(t) \le h(t)$, you can use DCT to have that:

$$\int_0^\infty g_n(t) \pi(\mathrm d t) \to 0$$

which proves what you are aiming for.

Comment: It's all very clear, thank you. Just a small question: when you bound the expectation of the integral by the integral of the expectation, what result are you using? Maybe it could be an equality if we can exchange the order of integration, which seems fine here? Or maybe is it obvious that the function is concave and you're using Jensen? Thanks again.

Comment: It is an equality. I am just exchanging the order of integration